# debug nuget in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, nuget, pdb-files

- I have a project A that produces a nuget N.
- I have a project B that uses N.
- I have a debug configuration for B, i.e. I can step through the code of B.

I also want to step through the code of A during debugging B, but it does not work just like this.

Since I build N from A myself, I can generate a `symbols` package and/or a `pdb` file, so I think I do have all that is needed. I just don't know how I can connect these pieces to allow me debugging the A-code from within the B-debugging-session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>` in my `csproj` files (both for A and B) did the trick.

I did not even need to copy the `pdb` file from A anywhere; it just worked on its own.

Might be that this is just due to my current setup: I have a `nuget.config` for project B where the path to project A is specified, because the nuget N is built there. And since it is project A's folder, its `pdb` is in there as well (in bin/Debug/frameworkVersion). Might be that VScode just checks the folder from where the nuget was retrieved, as well as all subfolders.

Anyway, if that won't work for a different setup, it seems it is enough to just copy the `pdb` of the code I want to debug (so, of project A's code) into the output folder of the project I'm currently debugging (project B). This can be achieved automatically by adding the `pdb` to the nuget as well as a corresponding `target` to copy the `pdb` to the output directory.

Then, if `just my code` is disabled, the `pdb` file will automatically be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?

https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#githubcom-and-github-enterprise

You need to add this in your csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
 
    <!-- Optional: Publish the repository URL in the built .nupkg (in the NuSpec <Repository> element) -->
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
 
    <!-- Optional: Embed source files that are not tracked by the source control manager in the PDB -->
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
  
    <!-- Optional: Build symbol package (.snupkg) to distribute the PDB containing Source Link -->
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Add PackageReference specific for your source control provider (see below) --> 
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I prefer doing it without any 3rd party libraries. I am (currently) the only one using Visual studio code for our projects, the other colleagues use Visual Studio. There, one can load symbol files during a debug session via GUI. So I do not want to add anything to the project just to get it running with my preferred IDE.